# Incrementing undefined object properties without performance penalty

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to increment both defined and undefined properties of an plain JS object without performance "penalty"?

```
var foo = {
  counter: 0
};

for (var i=10000; i >= 0; i--) { 
  foo['counter']++;
  foo['anyOtherCounter']++; // This should work as 'counter' but without errors 
}
```

Using conditionals (if statement or ternary operator) to check if property is defined is recognized as performance penalty.

Bleeding edge ES features are welcome.

Comment: How about `foo[x]=(foo[x]||0)+1`?

Comment: What's supposed to happen if you increment a nonexisting property? Silently ignore it?
Also, it's not possible, at least not in a more performant way than a simple if statement.

Comment: @Bart: [According to this test](http://jsperf.com/incrementing-properties), thg435's solution or even the ternary operator seem to be faster than a "simple if" :-)

Comment: @Bergi yeah but his solution sets foo[x] = 0 if it's undefined. If that's what you want, a single if statement *outside* the loop should easily outperform that statement *inside* the loop. No need for "weird" solutions and you can just use foo[x]++ inside the loop.

Comment: @Bart: No, to `0+1` if `foo[x]` was undefined! Of course, initialising the property outside of the loop will always outperform anything inside the loop.

Comment: @Bergi yeah, but that's my point. If the behaviour he expects is to set an undefined property to 0 (which he still did not specify), then micro-optimizations like ternary operators vs || are completely irrelevant. Just do a conditional check (whichever you prefer) outside the loop if you want to see *any* performance improvements at all.

Comment: @Bart: I would assume that he asks about properties whose names are not known before (because they are dynamic or so). The test (and the question) doesn't resemble that well, of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get around a conditional (of some kind) in the loop if you don't setup the property before.

I've set up a testcase at http://jsperf.com/incrementing-properties, it's actually not that much of a penalty if you don't coerce the `undefined` into a number.

> Bleeding edge ES features are welcome

I don't think so, they're rather likely to be not as much as optimized. [Proxies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) that yield `0` instead of `undefined` for non-existing properties might be an idea, though.

Comment: http://jsperf.com/incrementing-properties/2 - including the for loop which seems to be very relevant in this specific testcase.

Comment: @Bart: But then you must not forget about [initializing the object every time](http://jsperf.com/incrementing-properties/3)

Comment: as far as I know the setup block runs before every test so it wouldn't be necessary. It shouldn't have an impact anyway since it's the same overhead.

Comment: No, it does run before every test is measured in a loop. It *does* have an impact since it resets the object (and requires to go the `undefined` path) every ten-thousand iterations instead of every some-millionth time.